# Flutter Listview/Card/Tile with Details Page

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, expandablelistview

I am a beginner trying to start a career in flutter/dart.

I am currently working on a mini project and I need the help of someone to point me in the right direction or share the relevant tutorial links, I have searched around but I have not yet landed on what I need.

I am building an app and one of the screens should have a list of items from a Database (Asset SQLite). The data is going to be part of the app (Fixed). The data should be displayed in a listview to show {heading, subheading, and short text} for each list item. When Clicked, the item should expand to show Full text. The text is long with paragraphs. I intend to store it in an SQLite DB with fields id, title, subtitle, content. See the screenshot below for a sample of what am trying to do.

***The help am looking for therefore is; how to go about this. Where to start from, what packages I can use to achieve this. Links to Tutorials can also help***

> Think of it as a Book with Chapters but with No images

Also on another note, I don't know if there are better ways of storing this type of app data. Using the Book Model, the screen has about 100 Chapters. So it's a lot of data.

[Sample Image of What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp4gR.png)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is perfectly fine for your project. Though, for such kind of a data, I'll prefer to go with NoSQL DBs like Mongo Realm or Couchbase.

The package for Mongo Realm is [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mongodb_realm)

And the package for Couchbase is [here](https://pub.dev/packages/couchbase_lite)

But again, there is nothing wrong in using SQLite for this use case